# SQLAlchemy select distinct

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
    session = Session()
    query = session.query('count').from_statement(
        """
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT autoresponder.campaign_id) as count
            FROM autoresponder
            WHERE autoresponder.account_id=:account_id AND autoresponder.is_active='t'
        """
    ).params(account_id=account_id).all()

    print query[0].count
```

But I am trying to understand SQLAlchemy better and want to transform the above SQL statement into a SQLAlchemy ORM object that just returns the a count of distinct rows.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `Autoresponder` is a mapped class:

```
class Autoresponder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'autoresponder'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("account.id"))
    # account_id = Column(Integer)  # @note: probably a ForeignKey("account.id"))
    campaign_id = Column(Integer)  # @note: probably as well a FK
    is_active = Column(Boolean)
```

below query should do it:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
cnt = (session.query(func.count(Autoresponder.campaign_id.distinct()).label("count"))
    .filter(Autoresponder.account_id == account_id)
    .filter(Autoresponder.is_active == True)
).scalar()
print(cnt)
```